# Emulator Buzzing Sound

Tags: android

When I start my emulator whether in Eclipse or from command prompt, the emulator causes a buzzing sound, and will not exit, I MUST restart my computer.  When I add the -noaudio command line option, there is no buzzing, and the emulator will exit perfectly.  Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Some people on [googlegroups](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e110b9e4e4e054a4?pli=1) (and [others](http://gatheringclouds.blogspot.com/2008/09/sound-in-android-emulator.html)) have had success with

```
-audio oss
```

but it will block all other audio on your machine.